# Can we merge distro, distribution, distributions and linux-distro tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I think they are inherently the same thing and don't deserve multiple tags.

Breakdown of the tags:

- [distro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/distro) x 15
- [distribution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/distribution) x 40
- [distributions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/distributions) x 3
- [linux-distro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/linux-distro) x 14

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to salt and purge? I don't see the use of them... seems like having `programming-language` as a tag in StackOverflow.

Comment: I agree with @Jacob.  As this site is only about Ubuntu, there is no need for any of those tags.

Comment: But there could be relevant questions comparing distributions, or if you compare different flavours of Ubuntu, it could qlso be usefull. Merge would have been better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tags have been destroyed.

[Please care for the widows and orphans](https://askubuntu.com/tags/untagged).

Answer (score 4):

> Based on @jacob and @njallam

## Let's just destroy them!

This site is about Ubuntu, so none of these tags are needed. This is like having [programming-language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/programming-language) in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I think we should merge them. The people saying we should destroy them, what if the people are asking about Kubuntu, or similar distro's to Ubuntu. (I, personally, count Kubuntu, Lubuntu and all the other "untu" distro's as seperate fom Ubuntu)

Maybe their asking about the differences between Fedora and Ubuntu. These tags would apply. So, why destroy them?